# iOS AVPlayer: using addBoundaryTimeObserver() to pause() video at timestamp is accurate only 99% of the time

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, avplayer

This works beautifully 99% of the time. But for the 1% failure, the video will pause at an unacceptably distant timestamp.

```
self.timeBoundaryObserver = self.player.addBoundaryTimeObserver(forTimes: [NSValue(time: CMTime(seconds: timeStamp, preferredTimescale: (player.currentItem?.asset.duration.timescale)!))], queue: DispatchQueue.main, using: { [unowned self] in

            self.player.pause()

})
```

There is no discernible pattern amongst the failures.

I have a hacky solution that involves splitting the video into two separate videos, then the pause would occur when the first video ends... but I really just wished this simple code would work 100% of the time.

Maybe Apple will refine these functions in the future? I've seen unannounced improvements to AVPlayer in the past.

Here's Apple's documentation for the functions:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1388027-addboundarytimeobserver
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1387895-pause

I am absolutely not trying to advertise my app here, but you can see this bug live in my app on the iOS app store. The app is called "Voomoo".

Answer (score 2):

If you read the Apple Documentation here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1388027-addboundarytimeobserver

It is clearly mentioned here :

"Boundary times are arbitrary points of interest you define within the media timeline. As these times are traversed during normal playback, the block you provide to this method will be invoked. **You must maintain a strong reference to the returned value as long as you want the time observer to be invoked by the player**. Each invocation of this method should be paired with a corresponding call to removeTimeObserver(_:)."

try to update your code like:

```
self.timelineObserver = self.player.addBoundaryTimeObserver(forTimes: [NSValue(time: CMTime(seconds: timeStamp, preferredTimescale: (player.currentItem?.asset.duration.timescale)!))], queue: DispatchQueue.main, using: { [unowned self] in

            self.player.pause()

})
```

In this way "timelineObserver" will be retained and your observer will be surely called. Also you can later use "timelineObserver" in `removeTimeObserver(_:)` method to maintain balance between adding and removing Observer.

Comment: I do have this in my application. I did not include it in this question's code, just to keep the simple. But I've added after reading your comment.